# PhpSpreadsheet's COUNTIF Function php

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpexcel-1.8.0

I am working with PhpSpreadsheet(PHPExcel) to do an Excel in PHP and I got stuck when I needed to use COUNTIF. Here is my code:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(59,5,"=COUNTIF(BH7:BH125,'<>0')"); //BH POSITION
```

It doesn't work. If I putt /* BH7:BH125, 0 */ ,then it works but I want to use <>0. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It expects double-quotes for string parameter. Instead

```
"=COUNTIF(BH7:BH125,'<>0')"
```

try to use

```
"=COUNTIF(BH7:BH125,\"<>0\")"
```